# Unable to use any functions on a raster

Tags: r, gis, raster, tiff

I have uploaded a raster image (.tif) into R and it seems to have loaded fine, however I cannot use any functions with it. Library calls, and example code posted below.

[adding text here because stack exchange won't let me post without it but I don't have any more relevant info to add]

```
library(sp)
library(ggplot2)
library(raster)

# image
site <- raster("C:/Users/ichth/OneDrive/Documents/Restoration_Implementation/Design_Project/Site_Raster.tif")

> site
class      : RasterLayer 
band       : 1  (of  3  bands)
dimensions : 3597, 907, 3262479  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent     : 958324.5, 958778, 761774.5, 763573  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=tmerc +lat_0=24.3333333333333 +lon_0=-81 +k=0.999941177 +x_0=200000.0001016 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs 
source     : Site_Raster.tif 
names      : Site_Raster_1 
values     : 3, 221  (min, max)

> total_area <- cellStats(site, sum)
Error in .local(x, ..., value) : unused argument (warn = FALSE)
> plot(site)
Error in .local(x, ..., value) : unused argument (warn = FALSE)
> hist(site)
Error in .local(x, ..., value) : unused argument (warn = FALSE)

> traceback()
13: `crs<-`(`*tmp*`, warn = FALSE, value = prj)
12: `crs<-`(`*tmp*`, warn = FALSE, value = prj)
11: .fromRasterLayerBrick(from)
10: asMethod(object)
9: methods::as(x, "SpatRaster")
8: rast(object)
7: rast(object)
6: .readRasterLayerValues(object, 1, object@nrows)
5: readAll(x)
4: readAll(x)
3: .local(x, stat, ...)
2: cellStats(site, sum)
1: cellStats(site, sum)
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.4.2 raster_3.6-20 sp_1.5-1     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.9       rstudioapi_0.14  magrittr_2.0.3   tidyselect_1.2.0 munsell_0.5.0   
 [6] colorspace_2.0-3 lattice_0.20-45  R6_2.5.1         rlang_1.1.0      fansi_1.0.3     
[11] dplyr_1.0.10     tools_4.2.1      rgdal_1.6-2      grid_4.2.1       gtable_0.3.1    
[16] utf8_1.2.2       terra_1.6-41     cli_3.4.1        withr_2.5.0      tibble_3.1.8    
[21] lifecycle_1.0.3  vctrs_0.5.1      codetools_0.2-18 glue_1.6.2       compiler_4.2.1  
[26] pillar_1.8.1     generics_0.1.3   scales_1.2.1     pkgconfig_2.0.3 
>
```

Comment: Take a look and follow the advice here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383567/r-error-in-spcrssrs-string-fromwkt-unused-argument-srs-string-fromwk  Also make sure that the load of raster comes last so that any function with same name that might exist in other packages, such as `pkg::tidyr` to name one that has an overlapping function named `extract`, are able to be properly masked by the raster functions. Next time you should post more complete code including all `library` calls and show the output of `traceback()` and `sessionInfo()` so we do not need to guess about so many details.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited my post to include the things you asked for. I couldn't find anything in that link that was relevant, but I'm very beginner with R so I may have misunderstood some things. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From traceback the error comes from the `crs<-` function. Your version of `pkg:terra` is out of date. You should update it. My version is terra_1.7-23 and I am unable to reproduce the error. The help page for the current version of `terra`::`crs<-` says "warn" is a named parameter with a default of `FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I was even using that package or that I ever installed it. But I updated it and I am still getting same error

Comment: Actually, I updated it using "install.packages" and I tried "update.packages" but it's still saying version  terra_1.6-41

Comment: `terra` was attached by `raster`. To get the new version to load you need to quit R, remove any existing `.Rdata` files from your working directory, and restart.

Comment: I just downloaded raster for the first time yesterday though? is there a reason it wouldn't download the most recent version then?

Comment: I've tried everything I can think of. I've deleted and reinstalled R. I've deleted and reinstalled RStudio. I've quit and restarted R. Cleared ALL .R files from wd. I've updated the packages, etc. and I can't get a newer version of terra. Any ideas?

Comment: The .R files are no threat. It is the hidden “invisible” .Rdata files I was warning you about.  They are not shown in Mac Finder or Windows File Explorer unless you make a special effort to show them.

Comment: How do I show them? Wouldn't they be visible in the workspace window in RStudio? And sorry if my frustration is showing here but why on earth is this so difficult? I have never known it to be so hard just to update a program. I just tried to run Rstudio as administrator and updated all packages again and it was no use

Comment: Look up how to configure File Explorer to show dot-files. They are considered system resources and usually you should not mess with them but .Rdata files are created when you say ‘yes’ to the apparently helpful offered that appears when you ‘quit()’.

Comment: I finally figured it out. For whatever reason I needed to create a new directory to store packages. The old directory was unwritable, even after I specifically went to it and made sure it had all permissions checked. When I created a new directory everything updated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should have posted the error message and any warnings from the fail installation effort. You may also now need to change the value of `.libPaths()`

Comment: To answer your prior question you could have read the Rstudio docs: "RStudio’s Files tab by default shows only a selection of commonly needed hidden files, such as the .Rprofile. To instead show all of the hidden files, in the Files pane, click the More drop-down, then check Show Hidden Files."